# Что лучше применять для построения "чат"-бота

Tags: c#, бот, chat

Требуется не совсем чат-бот, а просто бот, отвечающий на весьма и весьма ограниченный круг вопросов. Нечто вроде бота-тех-поддержки. То есть не должно быть импровизации в ответах, ответы должны браться из определённой базы. Но вот суть вопроса, заданного человеком боту, должна быть понята вне зависимости от построения предложения. 
Хотел посоветоваться, как лучше это реализовать? Явно здесь пригодятся нейронные сети, но какие именно и в купе с чем (для максимальной производительности касательного сего вопроса)...

Comment: ничего не могу посоветовать по поводу построения собственных когнитивных инструментов и "баз", но общий тренд - обращаться за такими сервисами к облачным службам IT-гигантов (Azure, Google Cloud etc.) т.е тех, у которых такие "базы" есть

Comment: На мой взгляд проще воспользоваться готовым [фреймворком](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/creating-bots-in-the-microsoft-bot-framework-using-c-17590?l=ALwJe9kqD_4000115881).

Comment: я покопался и узнал, что ни [Google](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/languages), ни [Azure](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/text-analytics/text-analytics-supported-languages) пока не поддерживают семантический разбор текста на русском языке, только окраску можно определять

Comment: @СтаниславПечезеров Печально таки. Придётся как-то самому делать)

Comment: Whatsup, dude! Perhaps you have to read "[Creating a Bot Using C# and Microsoft Bot Framework](https://tutorials.botsfloor.com/creating-a-bot-using-c-and-microsoft-bot-framework-a344420f9d6f)" and https://dev.botframework.com/

Answer (score 1):

Советую не пытаться разрабатывать когнитивные сервисы с нуля: изучите лучше API [DialogFlow](https://dialogflow.com/). Он идеально подходит под вашу задачу, и к тому же, поддерживает интеграцию с многими мессенджерами и платформами.